# java.lang.StackOverflowError at Pattern.compile()

Tags: android, regex

I am getting java.lang.StackOverflowError exception while trying to do `Pattern.compile("[\\w ]{1,}");`. I don't understand the cause of this exception and how to overcome this. Can anyone help?

These are my patterns :

```
final Pattern namePattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w ]{1,}");
final Pattern roomPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w ]{1,}");
final Pattern mobilePattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{10}");
final Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile("^$|^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$");
```

Comment: not sure about the String entered. I can see this crash in Crashlytics. Is it possible for input string to cause this?

Comment: Do you mean the stack overflow issue comes up when the `final Pattern namePattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w ]{1,}");` is executed, or when a string is being matched?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : yup. its when Pattern.compile("[\\w ]{1,}") is executed. I can confirm it from the line number mentioned in Crashlytics report.

Comment: Why do you use `{1,}` and not `+`?